# Get an array of file names without extensions from a directory in Gulp?

Tags: npm, gulp

I want to get each of the file names in 2 directories (`helpers/` and `dialogs/`) into an array ***without the file extension*** using Gulp and/or NPM. Note that the array will be pre-populated with values - I need to *append* the file names to this array.

In other words, my directory structure is like this:

```
helpers/
    a.js
    b.js
    c.js
dialogs/
    x.js
    y.js
    z.js
```

I have this:

```
var modules = ['main-module'];
```

And I need to populate my array like this based on the directories:

```
var modules = ['main-module', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
```

How do I do that?

I have tried using the fs module [fs.readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path) along with [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename), but it would be nice to get this task done in a single streamed operation, if possible.

It would also be useful to get each directory into its own array for other operations - in other words, output a combined array and 2 individual arrays (total of 3 arrays) based on the directories.

```
var modules = ['main-module', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
var helpers = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var dialogs = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it easily with [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob), here is a code doing what you want.

```
var glob = require('glob');
var path = require('path');

var modules = ['main-module'];
var helpers = [];
var dialogs = [];

glob.sync("@(helpers|dialogs)/*.js")
.forEach(function(file) {
  var module = path.basename(file, path.extname(file))
  modules.push(module);

  switch(path.dirname(file)) {
    case 'helpers':
      helpers.push(module);
      break;
    case 'dialogs':
      dialogs.push(module);
      break;
  }
});
```